# Can't install linux on my laptop (Acer Aspire 5742)

Tags: linux, boot, bios, acer-aspire

In the last few days I'm trying to install linux on my laptop, but I'm not having success on it...

I create a bootable pen-drive with Ubuntu, but my laptop does not boot it...
seeking for solutions on internet, I saw there's a step in bios to turn boot mode to legacy, but I cant find it on my laptop's bios...

[image: PC Configs IMG Link]
[image: Boot options IMG Link]

Could you guys please, help me?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it in "Security"? The bios screen doesn't show any thumb drives connected. Are you sure the thumb drive works? If you can't find the legacy boot option, maybe you can create a uefi boot disk: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI